# How to find the email address an email was forwarded to (in MimeKit)

Tags: c#, email, mimekit

We have a catch-all email address and emails are being forwarded to [an-id]@ourdomain.com

We're then picking these emails up in code in order to process them...the processing isn't important.

```
        using (ImapClient client = new ImapClient())
        {
            var credentials = new NetworkCredential(settings.Value.Email.User, settings.Value.Email.Password);
            var uri = new Uri("imaps://" + settings.Value.Email.Server);
            client.Connect(uri);
            client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
            client.Authenticate(credentials);
            client.Inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadWrite);

            IList<IMessageSummary> messages = null;

            foreach (var message in client.Inbox.Fetch(0, -1, MessageSummaryItems.Full | MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId | MessageSummaryItems.BodyStructure))
            {
                // Processing
            }
        }
```

However, the "message.Envelope.To.Mailboxes" contains the original email address the email was sent to (myemail@gmail.com) and not the email address it was forwarded to ([an-id]@ourdomain.com).  As far as I can tell, [an-id]@ourdomain.com doesn't appear anywhere in the envelope.

Is there a way to find this email address? (we need the ID basically for routing).

Or is there a different method I should be using to achieve this (routing email to *somewhere* with an ID I can use for processing).

Comment: Maybe you could find the original email using Envelope.InReplyTo  (return email-Id ) and then go to that email and get the address . You can verify first using MessageSummary.IsReply  . 
 http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/P_MailKit_Envelope_InReplyTo.htm

Comment: InReplyTo is null alas

Comment: MessageSummary.IsReply is true? and InReplyTo is null? That method looks for strings like "RE", "FWD"

Comment: IsReply is false, and InReplyTo is null - it's not a reply, it's a forward (like in gmail, "forward all emails to..."), so I don't think it's an official "reply"

Answer (score 2):

There are some headers on the emails with this information in:
X-Orig-To or X-Forwarded-To

```
            var fields = new HashSet<string>(){ "X-Orig-To", "X-Forwarded-To" };
            foreach (var message in client.Inbox.Fetch(0, -1, MessageSummaryItems.Full | MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId | MessageSummaryItems.BodyStructure, fields))
            {
                  var email = message.Headers["X-Orig-To"];
            }
```

These seem to contain the destination email address, and solves the problem.

**I'm not currently sure why there are more than one, or if these are standardised